# How to use Microsoft Identity services in a React.NET template from .NET CLI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm working on a project where I need to implement authentication and authorization using Microsoft Identity services in a React.NET template created using the .NET CLI. I've already set up the basic template using the following command:

```
*dotnet new react -o MyReactApp*
```

Now, I want to integrate Microsoft Identity services into my React application. I've done some research, but I couldn't find any clear guidance on how to achieve this specific setup.

Can someone please provide step-by-step instructions or point me to relevant resources on how to use Microsoft Identity services in a React.NET template from the .NET CLI? Specifically, I need to be able to authenticate users, handle user registration, and implement role-based authorization.